# How to completely disable transactions in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to automate the concurrent creation of PostgreSQL indexes via Django. However, when I try to execute SQL via Django like:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['mydb'].cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY some_index ON some_table (...)')
```

I get the error:

```
DatabaseError: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot run inside a transaction block
```

Even if I use the old `@commit_manually` decorator or the new @atomic decorator, I still get this error. How do I completely disable transactions in Django?